# Is it necessary to do threading for sending emails in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am not sure that if it is necessary to use thraeding for sending emails in django or not ? If we need to do it so Can i just use the threading library instead of Celery or rabbitmq ?

Comment: Threading in a production setup can have weird side-effects. The WGSI server manages processes and threads and adding new once may bring that out or order.

Comment: So I have to use the celery right?

Comment: Depends how fast your email service sends emails and how long it's acceptable to make the user wait. I use a queue (celery) to send most emails but there are alternatives to celery such as https://github.com/rq/django-rq or https://github.com/Koed00/django-q

Comment: web servers usually have limited time to generate response for user request - ie. Apache has 30seconds and after that time it can kill process. All this to prevent attack [DDoS](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDoS). If you execute long-running code directly when django generates response then server may kill it. Celery run as separated program so it can run code long time.